# C# test if list is empty()

Tags: c#

How to do it?

Is it list.Count == 0?

Thanks

Comment: What is `empty()` in C#?

Comment: Both expressions evaluate to a boolean result. Both results are `true` if the list is empty, `false` if not. So yes, in terms of the expression's result they should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant (`Count` is a property, not a method):

```
list.Count == 0
```

And the answer is yes. Microsoft documentation explicitly says: "Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation."